# WCF launching : Failed to add a service

Tags: c#, wcf, service

I've got a problem with my WCF. My Service Contract Interface is :

```
namespace A.B.C
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IWSpExporter
    {
        [OperationContract]
        int ExportFile();

        [OperationContract]
        int ExportMetaData();

        [OperationContract]
        int ExportAll();
    }
}
```

And of course I have the class :

```
namespace A.B.C
{
    class WSpExporter : IWSpExporter
    {

        public int ExportFile() 
        {
            return 0;
        }

        public int ExportMetaData()
        {
            return 0;
        }

        public int ExportAll()
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

And my App.config is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>

      <service name="A.B.C.WSpExporter"
               behaviorConfiguration="WSpExporterBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/WSpExporter/service"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>

        <!-- this endpoint is exposed at the base address provided by host: http://localhost:8000/WSpExporter/service-->
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  contract="A.B.C.IWSpExporter">
          <identity>
            <servicePrincipalName value="host/localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>

        <!-- this endpoint is exposed at the base address provided by host: http://localhost:8000/WSpExporter/service/mex -->
        <endpoint address="mex" 
                  binding="mexHttpBinding" 
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />

      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WSpExporterBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Then I compile and install my service. I see it correctly launched in the Windows GUI where you can see all the services launched...

But when I try to access to : `http://localhost:8000/WSpExporter/service`, i've no result.

And when I try to add my service to WcfTestClient, I've the following error :

> Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible. Make sure your service is running and exposing metadata.

I dont understand where is my problem...

EDIT : (All the Service code is not here...)

```
namespace A.B.C
{
class PExporter : ServiceBase
{
  public static void Main()
    {
        ServiceBase.Run(new PExporter());
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {

        if (serviceHost != null)
        {
            serviceHost.Close();
        }

        serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(PExporter));

        serviceHost.Open();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        if (serviceHost != null)
        {
            serviceHost.Close();
            serviceHost = null;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your class `PExporter` does not seem to be `public`, or did you just not paste that? Ultimately you'll want to attach the debugger to the running service process to check for variables and exceptions, but you can also add logging. Does the ServiceHost actually start? What is its endpoint? What does [WCF Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) say about your services? What does `netstat -ab` tell you, is it listening? Do you have a firewall blocking `localhost` connections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my error :

The method :

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{

    if (serviceHost != null)
    {
        serviceHost.Close();
    }

    serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(PExporter)); // ERROR HERE

    serviceHost.Open();
}
```

launch a wrong class... Correction :

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{

    if (serviceHost != null)
    {
        serviceHost.Close();
    }

    serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(WSpExporter)); //GOOD NOW

    serviceHost.Open();
}
```